# Arranging items in cycle using CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Center focus image]

Hello All,

Sorry to bother you with this. I'm trying to arrange a list of items from a database using CSS as shown below, On clicking or mouse overing any of the item, that item will display the enlarge size in the center.

Please how can i achieve this. Any link to any tutorial will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using jquery library,
you can append data to any element in your html file
for example

```
$("#"+id).data("sort_id":num);
```

and then restore this data later

```
var sort_id  = $("#"+id).data("sort_id");
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that was not what i was looking for. I actually need the html and css markup in achieving the above image display.